# How to tackle ValueError?

Tags: python

I have the following code which is giving me error. I tried to change the if condition but it seems the problem is somewhere else. I will appreciate any help.

```
if humanRegion_bbs and belongings_bbs :
            x_left = max(humanRegion_bbs[0],belongings_bbs[0])
            y_top = max(humanRegion_bbs[1],belongings_bbs[1])
            x_right = min(humanRegion_bbs[2],belongings_bbs[2])
            y_bottom = min(humanRegion_bbs[3],belongings_bbs[3])
```

traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/prashant/anaconda3/envs/vaak_p36/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/process.py", line 258, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "/home/prashant/anaconda3/envs/vaak_p36/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/process.py", line 93, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "appMulti.py", line 677, in worker_processCamera
    oneObject.setBelongings(image,humanRegion_bbs,belongings_bbs)
  File "./deepPose/tracking.py", line 648, in setBelongings
    x_left = max(humanRegion_bbs[0],belongings_bbs[0])
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

I expect both humanRegion_bbs and belongings_bbs to be some numbers. Is it because of some other line of code?

Comment: The problem is in your `if` clause. What do you mean by `if humanRegion_bbs and belongings_bbs`? Do you expect them to be all filled in with some numbers, or to have at least one non-zero value?

Comment: @Selcuk  I expect both humanRegion_bbs and belongings_bbs to be some numbers

Answer (score 1):

If you expect your lists to have at least one non-zero element, you should use `any()`:

```
if any(humanRegion_bbs) and any(belongings_bbs):
```